# Under what circumstances the elements added from fragment showing under document?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio

I have a javascript project, and there is some code I used to create some sub-divs inside a div:

```
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
// code here to add divs in fragment
this._container.appendChild(fragment);
```

'**this**' is an object I created, and **_container** is a div. this._container is an existing div for sure. And after this._container.appendChild(fragment), the divs are correctly showing on my html form.

When I debug this in Visual studio the elements in fragment showing under document.

[image]

Anybody knows why? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That would depend on the context the code is run in, which sets the value of *this*.

Check the value of this._container.

Comment: this._container is an existing div for sure. And after this._container.appendChild(fragment), the divs are correctly showing on my html form.